# PhpStorm needs 777 permission to work

Tags: linux, phpstorm, laravel-5.4, phpstorm-2016.3

I used `chmod -R 775 *` to change the permission of all files in my project and `chmod -R 777 storage/` to change the `storage` folder permissions to grant all rights.

Now If I edit a controller in /app/Http/Controllers and try to save, then I get `Cannot save File, no permission`.

I have to change the permission to 777 to make it work, but I heard this is a security hole.

This must be a bug, is there a workaround?

Comment: please go to Controllers folder via terminal, add type ll, afer hint enter and please write result( cd ../path_to controller && ll).

Comment: Yes, it **is** a security hole! I'd suggest to check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30746378/3975480) :)